# Fill container slide-show bug

Tags: javascript, html, css, containers

Well, what i'm trying to do is a slide-show with a overlapping caption when hovering the its container or image. The image must be exact fit to the container box so it won't show the scroll-bar and the border radius is correct. I was able to do it, however there's a bug. When the page is loaded first it's normal, but a flickering happens and the scroll-bar appears, or the inverse (first the scroll-bar is there and then is not). Is there a way to resolve this?

[image: This is what is supposed to happen (and happens at first - or last)]

[image: enter Correct hover behaviour]

[image: The error]

I tested with Chrome and Firefox and both presents the same incorrect behaviour.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  } else if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#header {
  background-color: #202020;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: auto;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.navbar {
  font-family: "Roboto Thin";
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 48px;
  margin-left: 400px;
}

#login {
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 57px;
  padding-right: 35px;
}

#login li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.titulo {
  font-family: "Roboto Light";
  font-size: 45pt;
}

img#mds-modern {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 15px;
  height: 100px;
}

img#mds-logo {
  float: left;
  height: 120px;
}

div.body {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.carousel-container {
  max-width: 773px;
  max-height: 509px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.slide {
  display: none;
}

.slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.caption {
  height: 50px;
  color: rgba(242, 242, 242, 0);
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-family: "Roboto Thin";
  padding-top: 12.5px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.carousel-container:hover .caption {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.8));
  color: #f2f2f2;
  transition: background 2s;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="pt-br">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Malucos do Sealp</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
  <script language="javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header-container">
    <nav>
      <header id="header">
        <img id="mds-logo" src="MDS.png" alt="Escudo MDS">
        <img id="mds-modern" src="MDS Modern Logo.png" alt="MDS Logo Moderna">

        <ul class="navbar" id="login">
          <li>Login</li>
          <li>|</li>
          <li>Seja Um Maluco</li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="navbar">
          <li>Notícias</li>
          <li>Loja</li>
          <li>História</li>
          <li>Jogadores</li>
        </ul>

      </header>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="body">
    <div class="carousel-container">

      <div class="slide fade">
        <img src="MDS Anúncio.jpg" alt="Anúncio de novos uniformes">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Novo uniforme para a temporada</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slide fade">
        <img src="MDS Produto.jpg" alt="Produto uniforme">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Compre já seu uniforme</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slide fade">
        <img src="MDS Reborn.jpg" alt="Reborn">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>MDS REBORN</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- The dots -->
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </div>
  <script>
    showSlides(0)
  </script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, figured out how to do it. Instead of applying border-radius to the parent carousel-container, I've applied it to the caption and the images. Furthermore, I have removed the overflow property of the parent.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}


/****************************************************
*                                                   *
*                     Header                        *
*                                                   *
****************************************************/

#header {
  background-color: #202020;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: auto;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.navbar {
  font-family: "Roboto Thin";
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 48px;
  margin-left: 400px;
}

#login {
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 57px;
  padding-right: 35px;
}

#login li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.titulo {
  font-family: "Roboto Light";
  font-size: 45pt;
}

img#mds-modern {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 15px;
  height: 100px;
}

img#mds-logo {
  float: left;
  height: 120px;
}


/****************************************************
*                                                   *
*                      Body                         *
*                                                   *
****************************************************/

div.body {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.carousel-container {
  max-width: 773px;
  max-height: 509px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.slide {
  display: none;
}

.slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.caption {
  height: 50px;
  color: rgba(242, 242, 242, 0);
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-family: "Roboto Thin";
  padding-top: 12.5px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.carousel-container:hover .caption {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.8));
  color: #f2f2f2;
  transition: background 2s;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```